# Grouping consecutive duplicates in a list?

Tags: list, haskell

Very basic but I'm finding the problem frustrating. I'm trying to group consecutive elements of a list:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5]
```

becomes

```
myList = [[1],[2],[3],[4,4,4],[5]]
```

This is my attempt using foldr with an accumulator:

```
print $ foldr (\ el acc -> if el /= head (head acc) then el ++ (head acc) else acc) [['a']] myList
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘Int’
In the expression: 'a'
In the expression: ['a']
In the second argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘[['a']]’
```

Any advice would be great!

Comment: `el ++ head xs` has type `[a]` but the accumulator has type `[[a]]`. You cannot return different types in an `if` statement.

Comment: Are you not aware of [`Data.List.group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a fold on lists requires us to answer just two cases: `[]` (the empty list, or "nil") and `x:xs` (an element followed by a list, or "cons").

What is the answer when the list is empty? Lets say the answer is also an empty list. Therefore:

```
nilCase = []
```

What is the answer when the list is not empty? It depends on what we have already accumulated. Lets say we have already accumulated a group. We know that groups are non-empty.

```
consCase x ((g11:_):gs)
```

If `x == g11` then we add it to the group. Otherwise we begin a new group. Therefore:

```
consCase x ggs@(g1@(g11:_):gs)
  | x == g11  = (x:g1):gs
  | otherwise = [x]:ggs
```

What if we have not accumulated any groups yet? Then we just create a new group.

```
consCase x [] = [[x]]
```

We can consolidate the three cases down to two:

```
consCase x ggs
  | g1@(g11:_):gs <- ggs, x == g11 = (x:g1):gs
  | otherwise                      = [x]:ggs
```

Then the desired fold is simply:

```
foldr consCase nilCase
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `foldr`, it should be:

```
group :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group = foldr (\x acc -> if head acc == [] || head (head acc) == x then (x:head acc) : tail acc else [x] : acc) [[]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of your case case is `[[Char]]`, you are attempting to build a value of type `[[Int]]`. Our base case should be an empty list, and we'll add list elements in each step.

Let's look at the anonymous function you're written next. Note that we'll fail due to type based on your current `if` within the accumulator (they must return values of the same type, and the same type as the accumulator. It'll be better, and cleaner, if we pattern match the accumulator and apply the function differently in each case:

```
func :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
func = foldr f []
  where f x []        = undefined
        f x (b@(b1:_):bs)
            | x == b1   = undefined
            | otherwise = undefined
```

When we encounter the base case, we should just add the our element wrapped in a list:

```
f x [] = [[x]]
```

Next, we'll deal with the non-empty list. If x is equal to the next head of the head of the list, we should add it to that list. Otherwise, we shou

```
f x (b@(b1:_):bs)
  | == b1   = (x:b):bs
  | = [x]:b:bs
```

Putting this together, we have:

```
func :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
func = foldr f []
  where f x []        = [[x]]
        f x (b@(b1:_):bs)
          | x == b1    = (x:b):bs
          | otherwise = [x]:b:bs
```

Having broken the problem down, it's much easier to rewrite this more compactly with a lambda function. Notice that the `head` `[[]]` is just `[]`, so we can handle the empty list case and the equality case as one action. Thus, we can rewrite:

```
func :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
func = foldr (\x (b:bs) -> if b == [] || x == head b then (x:b):bs else [x]:b:bs) [[]]
```

However, this solution ends up requiring the use of `head` since we must pattern match all versions of the accumulator.

Comment: I'd argue the first, less compact version is the better one. It is more readable, doesn't test for an empty list with `(==)` (doing that brings in an `Eq` constraint needlessly, though in this specific case you'd need `Eq` anyway), and gives `[]` rather than `[[]]` for the empty list, which is a more natural result. On this last point: one might ask to which element a `[]` "group" corresponds, or whether the last element of `func xs` should always be `[]`, given that all lists eventually end with an empty list. Using `[]` rather than `[[]]` as the initial accumulator avoids such questions.